# I mix between a text and a math editor

Tags: text-editor, math

I'm looking for a software like Word, but able to do math calculations, so that you can write text that explains the math, and then show some calculations. Like TI-Nspire CAS (which I find a bit annoying when it comes to formatting)

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editors only? If not, have a look at LaTeX.

Comment: Looks useful, but WYSIWYG would fit my work even more, even though I don't think it exists

Comment: How about http://www.lyx.org/ ? But LaTex won't do the calculations for you.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt A quick search revealed [LaTeXCalc](http://latexcalc.sourceforge.net/), which is similar to C and C++' preprocessors. Nevertheless, LaTeX is by all means not the right tool for calculations but for showing their results.

Comment: @ComFreek Cool, I wasn't aware of this tool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest installing [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) for what you are looking for - to quote the web page:

> The IPython Notebook is a web-based interactive computational
>   environment where you can combine code execution, text, mathematics,
>   plots and rich media into a single document.

It is:

- free (both gratis and FOSS)
- Cross Platform so you can use it on Windows, Mac, Linux
- Consist of a series of cells containing one of:

  1. Code - This is syntax highlighted python and can be executed.
  2. Markdown - This can be rendered to Rich Text
  3. Headings - These can be used to generate table of contents and are rendered as rich text.
  4. Raw output - Placed directly in the cell for example, this allows you to type full LaTeX into a raw cell, which will only be rendered by LaTeX after conversion by nbconvert.
  5. Full matplotlib functionality within the notebook allows graphs, etc., to be used.
  6. Your user interface is in a browser of your choice.

Some examples, (themselves ipython notebooks):

- [matplotlib](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb)
- [markdown](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/Notebook/Markdown%20Cells.ipynb)
- [typesetting maths](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Math%20Using%20MathJax.ipynb) e.g.:
  [image: typesetting maths]
- [Example from a real lecture](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/qutip-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-2B-Single-Atom-Lasing.ipynb):
  [image: Example from a real lecture]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [publishing feature of Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html):

> Publishing creates a formatted document that includes your code,
>   comments, and output. Common reasons to publish code are to share the
>   documents with others for teaching or demonstration, or to generate
>   readable, external documentation of your code.

[image]

- non-free
- Windows, Mac, Linux
- supports LaTeX